# How to make line above footnote partial

Tags: css, footnotes

With CSS, I want to make the line separating my text from footnotes to be a partial line. Currently, it is a full line. Here is the css code.

```
@page {
  @footnotes {
    border-top-style:solid;
    border-top-width:thin;
    border-top-color:black;
    padding-top: 0.5em; } }
```

Any advice?

I would also like to be able to fit all my footnotes on one single page instead of having them pushed at times to the next page. But I'm not finding anything that will enable this.

Comment: That's not plain CSS

Comment: anycode usable ?  tip: gradient + background-size

Comment: Not sure I understand your tip. A little new to a lot of this.